# How to auto import laravel class in vs code

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code

I am currently working on laravel project in visual studio code text editor. If i use laravel package classes in the code at that time i want to automatically import that class using any vs code extension. If you know any best extension for this let me know.

For example I am using `Schema` class in the code then class should automatically imported like `use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;`

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Use `PHP Intelephense` extension by Ben Mewburn  for auto importing class name and many more feature. Install from vs code editor or check it [here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client)

Comment: It very helpful for php and laravel developers. It saves lots of time as well. Every php and laravel developers i recommend ```PHP Intelephense``` Extension.

Comment: I found this searching for a solution to automatically import classes because I'm used to this just kind of working well in PhpStorm. The problem with PHP Intelephense is the list of classes that it bring up for Laravel is so massive - one would have to refer to the manual for which exact one is needed. I was then referred to `PHP Namespace Resolver` for VSCode. Better but still a mission because list if quite big but more manageable.

In PHP Intelephense it's control spacebar and in resolver to import right click import.

Comment: Works for recognizing possible classes with `use` keyword. How about right-click and auto-import so it goes from `$a = new Foo\Bar\Class(); $b = new Foo\Bar\Class();` to `use Foo\Bar\Class; $a = Class(); $b = Class();`

Comment: But this extension are paid if you want to use with full functional

Comment: @Mahmud hasan ok I installed it, now how to auto import?

Comment: @Omar Write your Class name and hit enter

Answer (score 36):

**PHP Namespace Resolver** extension for VSCode works fine for me.

Comment: Actually, what I was looking for. works perfectly.

Comment: worked for me as well, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Intelephense is the best extension for auto import class.

Answer (score 0):

consider checking this out too: https://github.com/phpactor/vscode-phpactor

I use phpactor in my day to day, code intellissense, auto imports, refactoring tools like renaming classes and thus its references, navigation options (ie, move from source to test, mother or whatever), etc